# Is there a way to improve performance for $geoNear (MongoDB Aggregation) query with multiple conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I’m trying to use an aggregation query for $geoNear with multiple conditions in the query key.
the query is super slow (~800ms). But If I use the same query conditions without $geoNear but using $match with exact same condition it works well (~ 25ms). the query has mostly ( $in, $lte, $gte) operators. I don’t understand it works well without $geoNear. How we can improve the performance?
[Query here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2343327)

Comment: try create one index that include all of these keys

Comment: It mostly has an array of ids stored and I'm using $in for that. I don't think I can create index on multiple array fields altogether.

Comment: You do have several other fields there...